# java add hours to system date and in yyyyMMddHHmmss format

Tags: java

I am getting input as some date/time in hours(integer) eg: 2 hrs
I want to add this input hours to system date in yyyyMMddHHmmss format. How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean you want to parse in `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format?  Are you sure you don't mean you want to output in that format?

Comment: *Parse* or *format*? The system date isn't in text form to start with, so your question is a bit confusing... Oh, and do you want the system time zone, or UTC?

Comment: I think he wants to add the input in hours to the current date. The format it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this (assuming you meant *format* instead of *parse*):

```
int hoursToAdd = 2; //or from input
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, hoursToAdd);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: @DwB: Is that relevant if one is using `add`?  Whether it's a 12 or 24 hour clock doesn't seem to be relevant at all when it's a delta you're specifying, not an absolute time.  I think `HOUR` will work just fine.

Comment: Good catch.  You are correct.  I just tested it on java 1.6; add and roll work the same for HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                                 .print(new DateTime().plusHours(2)));
```

Comment: in my application we can't use this API. no jar and existing application.