# how to add 10 hour in current date and time in java

Tags: java, android

```
 9/4/2014 3:55:10 AM
```

here is my current date and time i want to add +10 hour so that i cam match with Current time of device please tell me how we can implement

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime =" 9/4/2014 3:55:10 AM "; 
        Date date = formatter.parse(currentDateandTime);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10);

        System.out.println("Time here "+calendar.getTime());    



    }
```

This Code am trying but i am not able to Impalement please help me where am doing mistake .

Comment: formatter = DateFormat.getInstance();  i think u are missing this line

Comment: Use compareto() method fro compare

Comment: This is not a proper answer but if you're working with dates on a regular basis the library Joda-Time is a must.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13853910/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7096366/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3581258/642706) and many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost working, but you have made a typo. You try to invoke `parse()` on `formatter` which has not been declared. Instead you have to call `parse()` on `sdf`:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    final String currentDateandTime = " 9/4/2014 3:55:10 AM ";
    final Date date = sdf.parse(currentDateandTime);
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10);

    System.out.println("Time here " + calendar.getTime());
}
```

Since you are using 12-hour system you can modify it like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    final String currentDateandTime = "9/4/2014 3:55:10 AM";
    final Date date = sdf.parse(currentDateandTime);
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10);

    System.out.println("Time here " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: BUt Am not change to PM why ?

Comment: I get following output: `Time here Thu Sep 04 13:55:10 CEST 2014`. I think this is PM.

Comment: here showing Time here Fri Sep 05 00:55:10 IST 2014

Answer (score 1):

If you operate on dates after 1970, adding 10 hours to given date can be achieved in one line of code:

```
Date d1 = new Date(); // or sdf.parse()
Date d2 = new Date( d1.getTime() + 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000 );  // add 10h in millis
```

**Output is:**

```
Thu Sep 04 13:56:39 CEST 2014
Thu Sep 04 23:56:39 CEST 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create a DateFormat. Try this:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String currentDateandTime = " 9/4/2014 3:55:10 AM ";
        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getInstance();
        Date date = formatter.parse(currentDateandTime);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10);

        System.out.println("Time here " + calendar.getTime());

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date   Error is coming d

Comment: Look at the imports, change your imports. clean java.sql.Date and write java.util.Date

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: " 9/4/2014 3:55:10 AM "
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at Test.main(Test.java:16)
  exception is coming can u please send complete code include import

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to figure out the current time of your computers clock you can do the following:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Which will return a long representing that timestamp. If you want it as a Date object you can do:

```
Date now = new Date();
```

As for the rest of your code the logic looks correct here is a snippet of my code that adds 10 hours to now.

```
Date now = new Date();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
Date plus10 = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(plus10);
```

Comment: actually this time coming from server 9/4/2014 3:55:10 AM    i want to  match with Pc time if i will add 10 hour